# How does Google Chrome launch Internet Explorer in the IETab extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

How is IETab able to launch Internet explorer in Google ?hrome? Can I launch other browsers like FireFox or Safari like Internet explorer inside Google Chrome?

My intention behind this is to know what language they are using to enable this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

They are rehosting the WebBrowser control.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752041(v=VS.85).aspx

Comment: @mathew Whited I am completely new to this concept. If you don't mind Could you please explain me with some code..

Comment: I avoid c++ and in .Net it would be in your control toolbox.  Follow the link above to MSDN for more help.

Comment: As the per the documentation I came to know that they are using Web browser control to make all happen. But here how can I call browser control from google chrome... Please help me